# If point $P$ varies on a circle about the center of rectangle $\square ABCD$, then $PA^2+PB^2+PC^2+PD^2$ remains constant

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Let $\square ABCD$ be a rectangle with center $O$. Prove that if a $P$ is a point that varies over a circle about $O$, then $PA^2+PB^2+PC^2+PD^2$ remains constant

Attempt:

[image]

Comment: Apply law of cosine: $PA^2=OA^2+OP^2-2OP\cdot OA\cos \angle AOP$, do the same for the other three pieces, then add...

Comment: This is true for every point in rectangle, not only on the circle about it's center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place $O$ at $(0,0)$ on the Cartesian Plane, and place $P$ at a point $(x,y)$ at a distance $r$ from $O$. Furthermore, place the vertices of the rectangle at the points of the form $(\pm a,\pm b)$, for the corresponding $a$, $b$. Then, $$PA^2+PB^2+PC^2+PD^2=$$ $$2\left(\left(x-a\right)^2+\left(x+a\right)^2+\left(y-b\right)^2+\left(y+b\right)^2\right)=$$ $$4\left(x^2+y^2+a^2+b^2\right)=$$ $$4\left(r^2+a^2+b^2\right),$$ which is clearly a constant. $\blacksquare$